# How can I add list element in Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

Now I have the classes like below:

```
class A {
    String? name;
    List<Friend> friends = [];

    A(this.name, this.friends);
}


class Friend {
    String? name;
    int? age;

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
            "name" : this.name,
            "age" : this.age
        };
    }

    Friend(this.name, this.age);
}
```

And I want to make Map which has `friends` list.
Like below:

```
{
    "name" : name,
    "friends" : [for(var f in frirnds) f.toMap()]
}
```

However, this map has only one element in `friends` list. It is inpossible to write each elements like below because the list length is not static.

```
{
    "name" : name,
    "friends" : [friends[0].toMap(), friends[1].toMap(), friends[2].toMap(), ... ]
}
```

What should I do if I want to add all elements of list in map?

Comment: there is a list of friend and you want to convert each item in that to a map then pass it to friends parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `map` method on `Iterable` and convert it to list like this:

```
{
    "name" : name,
    "friends" : friends.map((e) => e.toMap()).toList()
}
```